# Vuejs compute property doesn't get updated properly

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties, ag-grid-vue

I'm very new to Vuejs, I'm following their documentation which is very helpful. However, I find it difficult to understand how compute properties actually are triggered.

I'm using ag-grid for my project and I would like to update the total number of rows to my custom page size drop-down list.

The following is my code:

```html
<template>
     <div id="ag-grid-demo">
      <vx-card>
       <!-- TABLE ACTION ROW -->
       <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center">
        <!-- ITEMS PER PAGE -->
        <div class="mb-4 md:mb-0 mr-4 ag-grid-table-actions-left"></div>

        <!-- TABLE ACTION COL-2: SEARCH & EXPORT AS CSV -->
        <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between ag-grid-table-actions-right">
          <vs-button class="mb-4 md:mb-0" @click="gridApi.exportDataAsCsv()">Export as CSV</vs-button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ag-grid-vue
        ref="agGridTable"
        :gridOptions="gridOptions"
        class="ag-theme-material w-100 my-4 ag-grid-table"
        :columnDefs="columnDefs"
        :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
        :rowModelType="rowModelType"
        @grid-ready="onGridReady"
        rowSelection="multiple"
        colResizeDefault="shift"
        :animateRows="true"
        :pagination="true"
        :paginationPageSize="paginationPageSize"
        :cacheBlockSize="cacheBlockSize"
        :enableRtl="$vs.rtl"
        :modules="modules"
      ></ag-grid-vue>
      <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center">
        <!-- CUSTOM PAGESIZE DROP-DWON -->
        <div class="mb-4 md:mb-0 mr-4 ag-grid-table-actions-left">
          <vs-dropdown vs-trigger-click class="cursor-pointer">
            <div class="p-4 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light rounded-full d-theme-dark-bg cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-between font-medium">
              <span class="mr-2"
              >{{ currentPage * paginationPageSize - (paginationPageSize - 1) }} - {{ recordCount - currentPage * paginationPageSize > 0 ? currentPage * paginationPageSize : recordCount }} of {{ recordCount }}</span>
              <feather-icon icon="ChevronDownIcon" svgClasses="h-4 w-4" />
            </div>
            <vs-dropdown-menu>
              <vs-dropdown-item @click="gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(10)">
                <span>10</span>
              </vs-dropdown-item>
              <vs-dropdown-item @click="gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(50)">
                <span>50</span>
              </vs-dropdown-item>
              <vs-dropdown-item @click="gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(100)">
                <span>100</span>
              </vs-dropdown-item>
              <vs-dropdown-item @click="gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(150)">
                <span>150</span>
              </vs-dropdown-item>
            </vs-dropdown-menu>
          </vs-dropdown>
        </div>

        <!-- CUSTOM TABLE PAGINATION  -->
        <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between ag-grid-table-actions-right">
          <vs-pagination :total="totalPages" :max="maxPageNumbers" v-model="currentPage" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </vx-card>
    </div>
    </template>


    <script>
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue";
import { ServerSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model";
import { MenuModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/menu";
import { ColumnsToolPanelModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel";
import CompanyServices from "../../../_services/company.service";

import "@/assets/scss/vuexy/extraComponents/agGridStyleOverride.scss";

export default {
  components: {
    AgGridVue
  },
  data() {
    return {
      gridOptions: {},
      maxPageNumbers: 7,
      gridApi: null,
      defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        editable: false,
        resizable: true,
        suppressMenu: false
      },
      columnDefs: [
        { headerName: "Id", field: "id", filter: false },
        {
          headerName: "Company Name",
          field: "companyName",
          filter: true,
          checkboxSelection: true,
          headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true
        }
      ],
      rowModelType: "serverSide",
      modules: [ServerSideRowModelModule, MenuModule, ColumnsToolPanelModule],
      cacheBlockSize: 10,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    paginationPageSize() {
      if (this.gridApi) return this.gridApi.paginationGetPageSize();
      else return 10;
    },
    totalPages() {
      if (this.gridApi) return this.gridApi.paginationGetTotalPages();
      else return 0;
    },
    currentPage: {
      get() {
        if (this.gridApi) return this.gridApi.paginationGetCurrentPage() + 1;
        else return 1;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.gridApi.paginationGoToPage(val - 1);
      }
    },
   recordCount: function() {
      if (window.recordCount === undefined) return 0;
      else return window.recordCount;
   }
  },
  methods: {
    onGridReady: function(params) {
      var datasource = new ServerSideDatasource();
      params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.gridApi = this.gridOptions.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = this.gridOptions.columnApi;
  }
};    
window.ServerSideDatasource = function ServerSideDatasource(server) {
  return {
    getRows: function(params) {
      CompanyServices.list({
        startRow: params.request.startRow,
        endRow: params.request.endRow,
        SortColumn: "CompanyName",
        SortOrder: "asc"
      })
        .then(response => {
          window.recordCount = response.data.total;
          params.successCallback(response.data.rows, response.data.total);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          params.failCallback();
        });
    }
  };
};
</script>
```

My issue is that computed property 'recordCount' does not get updated as 'window.recordCount' being changed. 'recordCount' always shows value as zero.

Could someone please shed a light here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure about changing value? `windows.recordCount = 0` is not reactive.

Comment: I set the value at window.recordCount = response.data.total; Q1: does it make any difference with 'windows' instead of 'window'? Q2: assuming it's not reactive, how to set the recordCount value pass through the api call?

Comment: I made some changes to my question based on @DimaVak comment.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are setting recordCount on window instead of having it as a property in data in vue?

Comment: I tried having it as a property in data first but when I do so, I'm unable to access the same property via getRows method. I tried to access the property like this.recordCount but it didn't work. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of issues here, mainly that you are setting data and functions outside of the vue instance.

First of all, you should not be setting any data on window, Vue has plenty of ways to handle your data and makes it all reactive for you.

Start by moving your window.ServerSideDataSource function into the vue instance.
In Vue, functions are put under "methods", so after your onGridReady function, add a `,`
and then put:

```
serverSideDatasource() {
  return {
    getRows: functions(params) {..}
  }
}
```

Notice that I put serverSideDatasource with a small starting s, as camelCase is widely considered best practice when naming variables and functions.

Next, your window.recordCount should be put into Vue's data. Just add it after cacheBlockSize and set it like so:

```
recordCount: 0
```

Now that all your data and methods (functions) are within Vue, you can reach them by using "this".
So replace "window." with "this." all the places you use it.

Now, since your recordCount starts as 0, and is only changed when you call getRows, there is no need for a computed called recordCount, so delete that.

Notice: Having both a property in data and computed called recordCount would conflict, so even if you kept it, you would have to rename the computed.

Do tell me if this fixes it, or how far it gets you :)

Comment: Hi Thomas, I like your approach more but I'm struggling to execute it properly. when I moved the serverSideDataSource() inside the vue instance, I'm getting Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: serverSideDatasource is not defined" I'm refering to https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-pagination/

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to call "this.serverSideDatasource()" instead of "new serverSideDatasource()". let me try it and let you know the outcome, thanks!

Comment: Was just about to ask about that :)

Comment: I tried what you suggested. i.e. moved serverSideDatasource inside vue instance, removed the computed property, and pass it as a data property then finally assign the variable as this.recordCount = response.data.total;. Unfortunately, the value is still 0. I don't know if I miss anything.

Comment: it may be that page size drop-down gets initialized before getRows fires. any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: I also noticed 'this' is undefined insdie .then(response => {})

Comment: this is undefined inside the .then, because you are using a normal function, and not an arrow function. An arrow function will allow you to reach the vue instance on "this".

Instead of getRows: function () {...}
do: getRows: () => {...}

With that fixed, your getRows method should be able to update your recordCount.

Comment: Hi Thomas, it was a success and thank you for all your help, much appreciated!